# How can i watermark or stamp pdf file with active storage rails 7. Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rails-activestorage, vips

**I want to show watermarked PDF file to end user on .erb view file on my application.
For testing purpose firstly i tried to do this with jpeg image.**
My resources are;

1. [ImageProcessing Gem](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/vips.md#composite)
2. [ActiveStorage](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variation.html)
3. [Vips Gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Image#text-class_method)

This code is works but not yet watermarked.

```
 <%= image_tag @image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800, 800], colourspace: "b-w").processed if @image.variable? %>
```

---

This code is not working. Error is `VipsForeignLoad: file "http://localhost:3000/assets/placeholder-d1fde905b3fe89204148520108a99695bec9458f400d001b08626860983d5377.png" does not exist`

```
<%= image_tag @image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800, 800], colourspace: "b-w",  composite: [asset_url("placeholder.png"), "south-east"] ).processed if @image.variable? %>
```

---

Also i tried another approach which is not working too. Error is `overlay must be a Vips::Image, String, Pathname, or respond to #path`

```
<% water = ImageProcessing::Vips.Image.new %>
<% water.text("TEST KEYWORD")%> 
            
<%= image_tag @image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800, 800], colourspace: "b-w",  composite: [water, "south-east"] ).processed if @image.variable? %>
```

---

This is not working too. Error is like `no _dump_data is defined for class FFI::Pointer`

```
<%= image_tag @image.variant(resize_to_limit: [800, 800], colourspace: "b-w",  composite: [overlay: Vips::Image.text("asdfasdf")] ).processed if @image.variable? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with the following code.

In the controller:

```
@watermark_image = Pathname.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'watermark250x400.png'))
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= image_tag image.variant(resize_to_fit: [500, 500],
                  composite: [@watermark_image, :over, {x: 0, y: 0, premultiplied: true}]).processed,
                  class: "some-class", loading: "lazy", alt: "" %>
```

I think that earlier, I was trying to load the image by reading the file instead of just providing the pathname (sth like `water = ImageProcessing::Vips.Image.new(full_path)`, and that was when I was getting the same error:

```
no _dump_data is defined for class FFI::Pointer
```